# Running Batch file is normal but when running in Jenkins having error

Tags: jenkins, pywinauto

I have a problem for automation Test.
I use Pywinauto to test my program and it is working when I use Python 3.7 and run batch file in Windows.
However, when I use "Execute Windows batch command" and insert the batch file in Jenkins it doesn't start my application running with pywinauto but only running Python. Below is my batch file to run.

```
@echo off
C:
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"  "C:\Nam\Working\pywinauto\SPITest.py"
```

In my `SPITest.py` file I use the start function of pywinauto to open an App in Windows:

```
VisionAnalysisTool = Application(backend="uia").start('C:\KohYoung\KY-3030\Vision\VisionAnalysisTool.exe',timeout=5)
VisionAnalysisTool.VisionAnalysisTool.wait('enabled')
```

In Build in Jenkins I input in the Command of Execute Windows batch command

```
call "C:\Nam\Working\pywinauto\SPI_Pywinauto.bat"
```

This is Console Output in Jenkins:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\SPI_Winauto_Test
[SPI_Winauto_Test] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7879113300338047675.bat
 
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\SPI_Winauto_Test>call "C:\Nam\Working\pywinauto\SPI_Pywinauto.bat" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Nam\Working\pywinauto\SPITest.py", line 26, in <module>
    VisionAnalysisTool.VisionAnalysisTool.wait('enabled')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 530, in wait
    lambda: self.__check_all_conditions(check_method_names, retry_interval))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 375, in wait_until
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out
```

Comment: Please add information how you run Python/Pywinauto in the Batch Build Step and the relevant part(s) of the build's Console Output, too.

Comment: I have updated the information and Console Output above. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Is the leading `C:` in your first code box just a typo here or is this actually in your `SPI_Pywinauto.bat`?

Comment: the leading C: actually in my SPI_pywinauto.bat but not the same line with calling python.exe

Answer (score 0):

Error is the path which your given to start application

```
VisionAnalysisTool = Application(backend="uia").start('C:\KohYoung\KY-3030\Vision\VisionAnalysisTool.exe',timeout=5)
```

In this line of code `'C:\KohYoung\KY-3030\Vision\VisionAnalysisTool.exe'` is the path of the application. But you NOT used to escape the backslash.

So you can do one of these

```
VisionAnalysisTool = Application(backend="uia").start(r'C:\KohYoung\KY-3030\Vision\VisionAnalysisTool.exe',timeout=5)
```

or

```
VisionAnalysisTool = Application(backend="uia").start('C:\\KohYoung\\KY-3030\\Vision\\VisionAnalysisTool.exe',timeout=5)
```

This will help you to open the application

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it doesn't work. Jenkins is aimed work in background mode not interactive mode. So I am finding out a solution to running in interactive mode.

Comment: @SonnyMinhVu What is the error now after this change ? And by the way you need to correct as above answer in the code

Comment: Does your bat file run on a standalone machine without any issue?

Comment: yes, it only happen when we run in Jenkins

Comment: how are disconnecting from machine if your using remote desktop.  There is procedure to disconnect from machine .

Comment: Actually, I want to run this automation test like opening this caculator and  sum 2 numbers by Jenkins as the link below. But don't know how to configure for Jenkins. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCdowaoS5NU